# SFMCSdk Android - Request manager with status 429 too many requests

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, android, react-native, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

Android SDK RequestManager often logging with registration status "Too Many Requests - 429"

Can someone explain what are the impacts of this in the registration process in Marketing Cloud? Why is this happening and is there a way to prevent this?

**React Native info:**

```
"react-native": "0.72.8",
"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^8.1.0"
```

**SFMCSdk info:**

```
"sfmcSDKVersion": "1.0.3",
"sdk_Version": "8.1.5",
```

**Request Manager Log:**

*mc_app_server_id and mc_application_id omitted for security reasons

```
"RequestManager": {
  "https://<mc_app_server_id>.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/<mc_application_id>/sync/c74ace6c-588b-419b-97f6-1e91ce14f9a3": "Accepted - 202",
  "https://<mc_app_server_id>.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/registration": "Too Many Requests - 429"
},
"AlarmScheduler": {
  "pending_alarms": {
    "REGISTRATION": "2024-03-12T18:58:21.822Z"
  }
},
```

**Android configuration in MainApplication.java:**

```
SFMCSdk.configure((Context) this, SFMCSdkModuleConfig.build(builder -> {
      builder.setPushModuleConfig(MarketingCloudConfig.builder()
              .setApplicationId(BuildConfig.mc_application_id)
              .setAccessToken(BuildConfig.mc_access_token)
              .setSenderId(BuildConfig.fcm_sender_id)
              .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(BuildConfig.mc_app_server_url)
              .setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
              .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
                  R.drawable.ic_notification
                )
              )
              .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
              .build(this));

      return null;
    }), initializationStatus -> {
        Log.e("STATUSS", String.valueOf(initializationStatus.getStatus()));
      if (initializationStatus.getStatus() == 1) {
          Log.e("STATUSS", "STATUS SUCCESS");
      } else {
        Log.e("STATUSS", "Error");
        Log.e("STATUSS", String.valueOf(initializationStatus.getStatus()));
      }
      return null;
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`429` is a simple DDoS protection built into the SDKs and can occur during normal operation or be triggered by the server if an application is behaving poorly.

There's nothing to worry about in the evidence you submitted above. Your application made a request, it was deferred, and you can see a future wake is setup to handle the request.